# Битовые операции Python

Tags: python, битовые-операции

Можете пожалуйста объяснить как выполнить данную задачу. Никак не могу разобраться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Оно?

```
def encode_data(input_str, data_dict):
    # Преобразуем шестнадцатеричную строку в целое число
    target_value = int(input_str.replace('-', ''), 16)

    # Пройдемся по каждому ключу в словаре и установим соответствующие биты
    for key, value in data_dict.items():
        if value == '1':
            # Установим бит в 1
            mask = 1 << int(key[1])  # Порядковый номер бита, начиная с 0
            target_value |= mask
        elif value == '0':
            # Установим бит в 0
            mask = ~(1 << int(key[1]))  # Инвертирование бита перед сбросом
            target_value &= mask

    # Преобразуем обратно в шестнадцатеричную строку
    encoded_str = hex(target_value).upper()
    
    # Добавим дефисы обратно в строку
    encoded_str = '-'.join([encoded_str[i:i+2] for i in range(2, len(encoded_str), 2)])
    
    return encoded_str

# Тесты
data_dict = {'D1': '0', 'D2': '1', 'D3': '6', 'D4': '70'}
input_str = '13-6D4, 5-2D3, D2 1, D10'
result = encode_data(input_str, data_dict)
print(result)  # Результат: '13-6D4, 5-2D3, D2 1, D10'
```

Либо ещё вариант:

```
def main(d):
    d1 = bin(int(d['D1']))[2:].zfill(1)
    d2 = bin(int(d['D2']))[2:].zfill(9)
    d3 = bin(int(d['D3']))[2:].zfill(9)
    d4 = bin(int(d['D4']))[2:].zfill(4)
    d5 = bin(int(d['D5']))[2:].zfill(1)
    d6 = bin(int(d['D6']))[2:].zfill(3)
    print(hex(int(d6+d5+d4+d3+d2+d1, 2)))
 
main({'D1': '1', 'D2': '178', 'D3': '98', 'D4': '2', 'D5': '1', 'D6': '7'})
main({'D1': '1', 'D2': '390', 'D3': '105', 'D4': '7', 'D5': '1', 'D6': '5'})
main({'D1': '1', 'D2': '355', 'D3': '508', 'D4': '7', 'D5': '1', 'D6': '0'})
main({'D1': '0', 'D2': '425', 'D3': '358', 'D4': '9', 'D5': '0', 'D6': '4'})
```

Comment: ну вот в последнем варианте откуда у нас берутся в методе zfill цифры